# What phrase means "the minimum you need to take part"?

Tags: metaphors

A while ago I came across a phrase that succinctly described how a new or existing business might need to offer some basic service in order to compete meaningfully. It may have been sporting or gambling related. The sentiment was similar to a "barrier to entry". It went something like...

> Coffee shop owners know that free wifi is *what you need to play the game*

Any ideas?

Comment: Entry fee. . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be thinking of "table stakes".

In its original meaning in poker, the "table stake" is an amount a player has to bet in order to participate in a game.

The term has been adopted in [business jargon](https://brandmarketingblog.com/articles/branding-definitions/table-stakes-business/) to mean exactly the concept you're trying to express; the minimum offering to be able to participate in a market.